# What does "edgy beat" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, music

> *Ólafur Arnalds mixes strings and piano with loops and **edgy beats** crossing-over from classical to pop.*

What does the writer mean by saying edgy beats? Does the writer mean it's not exactly classical, nor pop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this instance *edgy* is an adjective that is modifying the noun *beats*.

In this context [edgy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/edgy) means

> having a bold, provocative, or unconventional quality

and is somewhat (although not completely) synonymous with *cool* as in being trendy.

So I agree with your assessment: the writer is trying to convey that the beats (or rhythm) in the music are giving the classical music sounds of strings and piano a pop feel, by having an unconventional (in the context of classical music) quality.

Answer (score 4):

‘Edgy’ has been in use since 1976 to describe something ‘that challenges received ideas or prevailing aesthetic sensibilities; at the forefront of a trend.’ (OED) I fear my musical knowledge is insufficient to know exactly what is meant here, but the writer may mean little more than that the beats are unusual, a bit different.

Answer (score 2):

I've done quite a bit of research on this recently and my opinion is that an 'edgy beat' or 'edgy music' is such that rhythmically it doesn't flow graciously/groove in a danceable way or is harmonically dissonant, meaning that it has a lot of jagged edges. Like a saw compared to a butter knife.